# NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat Error reading .png file with ImageMagick

Tags: c++, image, opengl, textures, blender

I am trying to use ImageMagick to load a Mesh's (made in Blender) texture from using the ASSIMP library. The Mesh has a single material and a single texture.

I was attempting to follow two tutorials: [Tutorial38](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) and [Tutorial22](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial22.html).

The below code block is where it has problems;

```
bool Texture::Load()
{
    try {
        m_pImage = new Magick::Image(m_fileName); /* RIGHT HERE IT OCCURS */
        m_pImage->write(&m_blob, "RGBA");
    }
    catch (Magick::Error& Error) {
        std::cout << "Error loading texture '" << m_fileName << "': " << Error.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &m_textureObj);
    glBindTexture(m_textureTarget, m_textureObj);
    glTexImage2D(m_textureTarget, 0, GL_RGBA, m_pImage->columns(), m_pImage->rows(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_blob.data());
    glTexParameterf(m_textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(m_textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    return true;
}
```

It almost immediately exits the Try-Catch with the current error:

"Error loading texture, 'Resources/white.png': myproject.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat 'Resources/white.png' error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550

As far as I can determine ImageMagick is installed properly, I've attempted numerous times to compile it by hand but I always end up with Unresolved External errors with the new libs (they seem to be 2-3 mb bigger than the ones included with the Project).

The versions attempted:

ImageMagick-6.6.5-10
ImageMagick-6.6.0
ImageMagick-6.8.9
ImageMagick-windows zip from their instructions page.

A big problem I have when attempting the self installer binaries is that they don't include both the Release Candidate AND the Debug lib's, when the code requires both; while the source versions I compile as mentioned aren't correct and result in Unresolved External errors or don't otherwise clearly deposit their Include and Lib folders.

I've contacted the developer of the tutorial but the only thing he's said so far is that I might have the wrong version of ImageMagick installed and is incompatible with the version he includes... Without saying which version the correct one would be.

Edit - 1:
-Attempted installation/reinstallation of libpng from [Here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm) No change.

Comment: Do you have `libpng` installed as well?  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: When I type identify -list format it's listed as native/read/write, it should be installed I think, I'll try to see if I can reinstall it but it does the same error for jpg and any other file format.

Comment: Perhaps installing delegates might fix it, but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any instructions for a lay person; attempting to compile libpng just results in over a hundred compiler errors of not being able to find the correct files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, embarrassingly I found the solution after three+ months of elaborate torture, and it was to switch the compiler to "Release" mode instead of "Debug". I no longer complains and perfectly loads the texture I had.

Not working in "Debug" mode seems like either a bug with ImageMagick or a bug with Visual Studios 2010, I think I'll file a bug report.